# In MySQL, can we use the COUNT and SUM value to calculate a value in another output column using a single SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, sum, calculated-columns

Lets say we have something like:

```
SELECT COUNT(IF(Column1 = 1, NULL, 1)) AS "A", SUM(Column2) AS "B" FROM MyDatabase;
```

On the same query, can we add a column that would be A * B for example with one single SELECT overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either repeat the expression, or turn it to a subquery and do the computation in the outer query. Your expression is not that complicated (and can be simplified, as shown below), so I would go for the first option here:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Column1 = 1) a, 
    SUM(Column2) b,
    SUM(Column1 = 1) * SUM(Column2) c
FROM MyDatabase;
```

Comment: I see....sneaky...  Seems like the calculated column gave me A * B but without considering the IF(...).  The count should not be considered under some situations...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `column1` only takes on the values of 0/1, you can do:

```
sum(column1 * column2)
```

If it can take on other values, then:

```
sum( (column1 = 1) * column2 )
```

Both of these use the MySQL extension that booleans are handled as numbers, with "1" for true and "0" for false.